# PJSIP IPv6 registration issue in iOS 11.2.5

Tags: sip, voip, ipv6, pjsip, ios11.2

```
We have integrated PJSIP based SDK in our app and We are doing registration two times at the time of app launch. 

First time with "SIP EndpointId, Pwd" 

    status = pjsua_acc_add(&acc_cfg, PJ_TRUE, &acc_id);
    NSLog(@"Status of registration, %d", status);
    if (status == PJ_SUCCESS) {
         //Registration success
    }

Second with "Apple Token"

    pj_str_t name = pj_str("AppleToken");
    pj_str_t value = pj_str((char*)[hexToken UTF8String]);
    pjsip_generic_string_hdr_init2(&CustomHeader, &name, &value);

    pj_str_t ipv6Key = pj_str("X-IPv6IOSSDK");
    pj_str_t ipv6Value = pj_str("True");
    pjsip_generic_string_hdr_init2(&Ipv6Header, &ipv6Key, &ipv6Value);

    pjsua_acc_get_config(acc_id, app_config.pool,&acc_cfg);

    pj_list_push_back(&acc_cfg.reg_hdr_list, &CustomHeader);

    pj_strcpy2(&contactparam,";app_id=");
    pj_strcat (&contactparam,&value);

    acc_cfg.contact_uri_params = contactparam;

    pj_status_t status = pjsua_acc_modify(acc_id, &acc_cfg);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS){

    }
```

The issue we are facing here is:

In iOS 10.3 both pjsua_acc_add, pjsua_acc_modify are happening properly when we connected to IPv4 and IPv6 networks.

```
iOS 10+

IPv4 Wifi -----> Working fine

    a) Registration with (EndpointId, Password) ---> Going on IPv4 Wifi
    b) Modifying account registration with Token ---> Going on IPv4 

IPv6 Wifi -----> Working fine

  a) Registration with (EndpointId, Password) ---> Going on IPv6
  b) Modifying account registration with Token ---> Going on IPv6
```

However, in iOS 11.2.5 we have observed that pjsua_acc_add is happening on IPv6  and pjsua_acc_modify is happening on IPv4 when we connected to IPv6 wifi.

```
iOS11+(We have tested on iOS 11.2.5 with 4 different devices. It is happening with all devices )

IPv4 Wifi-----> Working fine

   a) Registration with (EndpointId, Password) ---> Going on IPv4 Network
   b) Modifying account registration with Token ---> Going on IPv4

IPv6 Wifi -----> Not able to Modify account

  a) Registration with (EndpointId, Password) ---> Going on IPv6
  b) Modifying account registration with Token---> Going on IPv4

Eventually, second registration(modifation) generating 'onRegistrationFailed' event.
```

Comment: do you get any fix for this yet ?